# RSS feeds for specific sets of questions

Tags: feature-request

I've noticed that there are RSS feeds associated to a given question, but unless my copy of Firefox is malfunctioning, I haven't seen a similar feed that would tell us e.g. about the latest unanswered questions.

The same observation actually applies to [Stack|Math]Overflow, so are these unavailable, or disabled by default, or completely uninteresting? I'm probably too addicted to this website anyway to avoid visiting it for a long period of time, but still, I'm under the impression that such feeds would be valuable.

Answer (score 1):

(I do not use a feed reader much, and I may be missing the point.)

I am not sure if the feed for unanswered questions is meaningful.  Since every question is obviously unanswered when it is posted, you will receive every question if your feed reader checks for the update to the feed frequently enough.

If the feed includes only unanswered questions which are at least a few days old, it might be useful, but that is at least something different from the [page of unanswered questions](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/unanswered).

That said, there are several (almost duplicate) discussions on Meta Stack Overflow for feeds for unanswered questions:

- [RSS for unanswered+tagged questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13849/rss-for-unansweredtagged-questions)
- [RSS for Stackoverflow's unanswered questions that matches my only favorite tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57300/rss-for-stackoverflows-unanswered-questions-that-matches-my-only-favorite-tags)
- [Why is there no RSS feed for /unanswered/tagged/tagname?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41696/why-is-there-no-rss-feed-for-unanswered-tagged-tagname)
- [Add an RSS feed for unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42525/anyway-to-get-a-rss-feed-for-unanswered-questions)

In the first link, someone points out a service to convert a usual page to a feed.

Comment: "I am not sure if the feed for unanswered questions is meaningful. Since every question is obviously unanswered when it is posted, you will receive every question if your feed reader checks for the update to the feed frequently enough." Indeed, but my point is that there does not seem to be such a feed. Anyway, thanks for the links, what I've read so far seems to indicate I was right: it's just missing.

Comment: @Anthony: And my point is that the feed for unanswered questions is useless (because a feed is not the right medium for dynamic information where _removal_ of items from the list is important).  If you agree with me that it is useless, why do you expect that that feed is provided?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your original answer. And I did not agree that it is useless ;-) But if I'm the only one to be interested in this, the moderators can close this question, I'll figure something out using your links.

Comment: @Anthony: You are free to disagree, but I already explained in my answer why it is useless.